# C++ removing file with filesystem library doesn't work

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a russian Roulette script written with C++. If two randomly generated numbers are the same, the script deletes a specified file.

People suggested to me that I should use C++17 for using the `<filesystem>` library in order to run file-related operations correctly. The removing operation runs if the conditions are matching. The `if` block runs correctly, but removing the file isn't happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <filesystem>
//include filesystem and replace remove() with filesystem libs remove function

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){
    int minNumber = 1, maxNumber = 6;
    int possibility,chamberNumber;
    srand(time(0));
    possibility = rand() % (maxNumber - minNumber + 1 ) + minNumber;
    chamberNumber = rand() % (maxNumber - minNumber + 1 ) + minNumber;
    cout << "First Number: " <<possibility<<endl<<"Second Number: " << chamberNumber<< endl;

    if (possibility == chamberNumber){
        std::filesystem::remove("C:\\Users\\mypath\\Desktop\\cppRoulette\\delete.txt"); 
        cout << "You're Dead " <<possibility<< endl;
        
    }
    // else{
    // cout << possibility << endl;
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

I use this line to compile my code:

```
g++ -std=c++17 rulet.cpp -o output
```

Here is a screenshot of the compiled output. Notice `"delete.txt"` still stands.

[image: compiled output]

I am using WSL Debian, because I am using VS Code and native terminals don't work proper with g++. I may like smoothness of Linux a bit more, though.

I am looking for a proper and easier way to deal with files, just like in Python. I am attending a C++ crash course, so I am trying to learn it, switching to Python isn't on the table.

Comment: what if you remove all the random number stuff?

Comment: FYI, when using `using namespace std;` there is no need for other `using` statements.

Comment: The likeliest thing here is that the path to the file you're trying to delete isn't quite what you've entered there. Especially since you're using WSL, which adds an additional layer of complexity to the proceedings.

Comment: You could also try the C function `remove`, but whatever is causing the filesystem code to fail will also likely cause `remove` to fail.

Comment: You could try replacing `C:\\Users\\mypath\\Desktop\\cppRoulette\\delete.txt` with `/mnt/c/Users/mypath/Desktop/cppRoulette/delete.txt`. You should also check the error you get.

Comment: *"native terminals don't work proper with g++"* Huh? I'd focus on this issue.

Comment: "native terminals don't work proper with g++" means I am struggling to work with cmd or powershell's weirdness. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is that g++ should just work in any of those shells, as long as it's added to the PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path is wrong. I just got your code to work on my system by changing the path from `E:\Test\delete.txt` to `/mnt/e/Test/delete.txt`.

Under WSL, all Windows drives (`C:`, `E:`, etc.) are mounted under the `/mnt` directory, in subdirectories that match the drive letter (`/mnt/c/`, `/mnt/e/`, etc). In order to convert your Windows path for use in WSL, you need to do the following:

1. Replace all backslashes (`\`) with forward slashes (`/`).
2. Remove the colon (`:`) after the drive letter.
3. Convert the drive letter to lower case.
4. Prepend the string `"/mnt/"` to the path.

After this, your program works, and will delete the target file.

Comment: Did you also try `E:\\Test\\delete.txt` (in code) which would match OPs code better? _"Replace all backslashes (```\```) with forward slashes (/)"_ - no, that would make each ```\\``` into `//`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, because ```\\``` in a compile-time string literal is only 1 ```\``` in the actual string data at runtime.

Comment: About separators on different platforms: see `std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I tried `E:\\Test\\delete.txt`. First thing I did, and as expected, it did nothing. To WSL, that path means nothing.